# AngularJs dependency Injection difference

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Is the array necessary ?

```
   app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){

}])
```

Will this work like the code above?

```
   app.controller('myController', function($scope){

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is always necessary, but it doesn't have to be combined into the controller definition.  There is a much cleaner way to do it, and its my preferred method. What I do is create the controller in a functional manner. So for example:

```
app.controller('myController', MyController);

//dependency injection done here using the array of definitions
MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];

//all of the dependencies are added as parameters into the controller function
function MyController ($scope) {
   //insert controller code
}
```

As pointed out in the answer by Sajeetharan, this is called the explicit method.  You should check out [this style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) that is endorsed by the Angular 1 team for other patterns that help make the code cleaner and easier to maintain

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work in the same way, its just the difference.You need to use **[`explicit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07#a-note-on-minification)** dependency injection(second way).

Even when you minify it converts $scope to variable a and $http to variable b, their identity is still preserved in the strings.

Comment: Thanks! It was just a simple question cause I never used the explicit dependency injection